# Youtube API no longer returning location data?

Tags: youtube-data-api

Has the YouTube API stopped returning location data ?

I can't find any official mention, but our CI tests are suddenly not seeing the data anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On June 1, 2017, an [entry](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#release_notes_06_01_2017) posted in YouTube Data API Revision History says the following properties are deprecated:

- recordingDetails.locationDescription
- recordingDetails.location.latitude
- recordingDetails.location.longitude

There is a [page in the YouTube Live help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7638112?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) that says Location tagging is only available on mobile live streaming, mobile uploads, and mobile edit. I do not know if this page is up-to-date.